# Horizontall scrolling with js and changing colors

Tags: javascript, portfolio

Im trying to do some one page portfolio.

So i come up with a solution how to change a black fixed text with white with the scrolling. the only problem is i don't know how to change this to horizontall scroll.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/a5a7x/5/

EDIT: i want to have an horizontall scroll, which means, that the color will change with the horizontall scroll not vertical like in my case.

[image]

Comment: off-topic: you might have a browse-issue, too. Your text is colored like a rainbow in chrome (outlines only). Weird issue with the z-index here.

Comment: It appears ok in my Chrome Canary and stable, but doesn't work on my FF Nightly nor stable.

Comment: will take a look at it.. that's wierd, cause i done this with chrome.. but i see now in FF, that there is a problem.. original the text on black background goes to white. I agree, some wierd issue with z-index..

Comment: do u know what could be the problem with z-index?